# Improve my function to reduce duplicated values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my array:

```
export const plantList = [
    {
        name: 'monstera',
        category: 'classique',
        id: '1ed'
    },
    {
        name: 'ficus lyrata',
        category: 'classique',
        id: '2ab'
    },
    {
        name: 'pothos argenté',
        category: 'classique',
        id: '3sd'
    },
    {
        name: 'yucca',
        category: 'classique',
        id: '4kk'
    },
    {
        name: 'olivier',
        category: 'extérieur',
        id: '5pl'
    },
    {
        name: 'géranium',
        category: 'extérieur',
        id: '6uo'
    },
    {
        name: 'basilique',
        category: 'extérieur',
        id: '7ie'
    },
    {
        name: 'aloe',
        category: 'plante grasse',
        id: '8fp'
    },
    {
        name: 'succulente',
        category: 'plante grasse',
        id: '9vn'
    }
]
```

And here is my code to remove the duplicate values:

```
const categories = plantList.reduce(
    (acc, plant) =>
        acc.includes(plant.category) ? acc : acc.concat(plant.category),
    []
);
```

Is there a better way to do this? I don't know why but React doesn't compile with the one-liner.

```
const categories = Array.from(new Set(plantList));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is using reduce and Map object. **This is a single line solution.**

```js
const plantList = [
    {
        name: 'monstera',
        category: 'classique',
        id: '1ed'
    },
    {
        name: 'ficus lyrata',
        category: 'classique',
        id: '2ab'
    },
    {
        name: 'pothos argenté',
        category: 'classique',
        id: '3sd'
    },
    {
        name: 'yucca',
        category: 'classique',
        id: '4kk'
    },
    {
        name: 'olivier',
        category: 'extérieur',
        id: '5pl'
    },
    {
        name: 'géranium',
        category: 'extérieur',
        id: '6uo'
    },
    {
        name: 'basilique',
        category: 'extérieur',
        id: '7ie'
    },
    {
        name: 'aloe',
        category: 'plante grasse',
        id: '8fp'
    },
    {
        name: 'succulente',
        category: 'plante grasse',
        id: '9vn'
    }
];

const uniqueData = [...plantList.reduce((map, obj) => map.set(obj.category, obj), new Map()).keys()];

console.log(uniqueData)
```